# pnpm: module not found

Tags: macos, npm-install, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

i have installed pnpm package globally using command 'npm install -g pnpm', after running this command on my terminal it shows installed. but when i check its version using 'pnpm -v' it doesn't shows 'pnpm: zsh module not found' basically it shows that module isn't installed. what should i do. also kindly tell me solution for macos

i have tried troubleshooting it[chatgpt solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96QWP.png).
also tried using the below solution, but couldn't implement it properly
To resolve the permission issue on macOS without using `sudo`, you can follow the third option I mentioned earlier, which involves changing the global npm prefix to a directory that you have write access to. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to do this:

1. **Create a directory for global npm packages in your home directory (if it doesn't already exist)**:

   Open your terminal and run the following command to create the directory:

   ```bash
   mkdir ~/.npm-global
   ```
2. **Configure npm to use the new directory as the global prefix**:

   Run the following command to configure npm to use the `~/.npm-global` directory as the global prefix:

   ```bash
   npm config set prefix ~/.npm-global
   ```
3. **Add the directory to your PATH**:

   Open your shell profile file (e.g., `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, or `~/.profile`) in a text editor. You can use the `nano` command or any text editor you prefer. For example, to edit the `~/.zshrc` file, you can run:

   ```bash
   nano ~/.zshrc
   ```

   Add the following line at the end of the file:

   ```bash
   export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
   ```

   Save and exit the text editor.
4. **Source your shell profile or restart your terminal**:

   To apply the changes to your current terminal session, source your shell profile:

   ```bash
   source ~/.zshrc  # or your specific profile file
   ```

   Alternatively, you can restart your terminal for the changes to take effect.
5. **Install `pnpm` globally**:

   You should now be able to install `pnpm` globally without using `sudo`:

   ```bash
   npm install -g pnpm
   ```

This approach will allow you to install global npm packages without needing elevated permissions, and it's a safer alternative to using `sudo` for global installs on macOS.

after the 3rd step

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why `npm i -g pnpm` did not work but there are [plenty](https://pnpm.io/installation#using-corepack) of other ways to install pnpm. The easiest one is running [`corepack enable`](https://pnpm.io/installation#using-corepack), which will make pnpm (and Yarn) available in your terminal.